# get rid of numeration when listing a matrix

Tags: math-mode, equations, matrices

how do I get rid of the extra numeration `(1)` in the bottom right corner?

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[-] when we look at the identity matrix: 
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0\\ 
    0 & 1 & 0\\  
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` to get unnumbered equations.

Comment: thanks it worked @moewe